# How the messaging can be used in case of request load is more?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I appeared for interview in one of the MNC software companies and the interviewer asked me a tricky question. 
He said suppose you have a system with users and its orders and there are user and order Rest services.
If user service is already scaled and orders service is not yet scaled then how the load on the orders service is managed. As user service is sending lot of request to order service to fetch orders. 
Can any one give me a tech stack to solve this problem. 
I think using a messaging queue could be the option, but how ? Or May be threading ...... Or both .... please help !

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know the context of the question and if it was related to messaging or not.

A couple of things you can take away from this scenario. I will assume the current integration is by API.

- Resiliency: If you are using sync calls from User service to Order service... the last one can be overloaded. Here you can use **Circuit Breaker** in User service to avoid cascading failures.
- Resiliency/Performance: Another way to handle backpressure is **Reactive Programming.** Take a look at Spring Reactor (one example).
- Resiliency/Performance: You can move from an API integration schema to **Messaging integration**. This way your User service and Order service can communicate in an async way. (E.g Publisher/Subscriber pattern).

Again, many things can be done (these are just a few), but the choice should be based depending the scenario.